# Which SE site is best for asking about self-learning/online CS education?

Tags: discussion, scope

I’m a programmer with little formal CS education, which has held me back career-wise, and where I think a lot of the fun is at.

I’m taking a sabbatical from work so I can teach myself CS fundamentals and explore other related interests.

If I want to ask questions or engage in discussions about educational resources for people like me or personal experiences of same, where on Stack Exchange should I go?

**Are the *Computer Science* main and meta sites the best places? Or are there better ones to consider?**

Comment: SE is good for asking questions *while* learning, not so much for learning itself or discussions. I think enrolling in a university program may be the best option, if you can reach (and afford) a university. There are other options on platforms like Coursera. Self-study from books and other material is obviously possible. The details depend on what you want to learn, specifically.

Comment: drop by [chat] its designed for _discussions_ the more the merrier :)

Comment: @vzn This is the answer that I’m looking for! Please put your comment in answer form so I can mark it as such.

Comment: This really depends on what you're really looking for, there's a lot of learning materials on the tag `references-request`. So as long as the question is not too broad I think this tag applies.